# "There’s no page at this address" error on Shopify Embedded App installation

Tags: laravel, shopify, shopify-app

I am facing a strange issue, When I install app first time on test store, installation goes smooth but after re-installation after OAuth, Shopify show me "*There’s no page at this address*" error.

My app submission was rejected due to this reason. I am using https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify library.

[image: This is image of error.]

Comment: What is the URL into the address bar that generates the error, you need to provide more information regarding it

Comment: @Onkar Please find URL generating error. https://callcouriertest.myshopify.com/admin/apps/1d3e2ca4dddb0c4af07f69862c44a5706e4/?hmac=af5ec532f62de9e15596dddcee5f893d57787aab31439d5a0d79896b1f3a619265f9&shop=callcouriertest.myshopify.com&timestamp=1610028042

Comment: You shared an URL of APP backend, which need to login to see anything or installation off

Comment: My public app is not listed yet. How can I share public URL? Or can I share what details required?

Comment: @Onkar I found the problem, Basically I did not implement app uninstalled web hook to delete previously install shop password. Due to this app was trying to load without authentication on second install. Thank you for effort.

Comment: @Mudasser how do you implement the app uninstall webhook if you've already uninstalled the app and don't have the previous access token anymore?

Comment: Basically, have to setup a webhook with topic "app/uninstalled" (https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/webhook) and remove previous installation of the user from the database.

Answer (score 15):

@Mudasser has answered his own question. You need to delete the old Shop (from the first installation) from the database then try the install again and it will work.

If you've correctly added the app uninstalled webhook you wont have this problem.

Comment: Sure, having the webhook registered should work 99% of the time. But if, for some reason, the webhook isn't called quickly enough (or not at all) or an error occurs when trying to delete the installation record in our database then a particular store will forever be unable to re-install our app.

How can we detect this on-the-fly and fix it automatically when it occurs (i.e. redirect to the permissions screen instead)?

Answer (score 2):

For those using Ruby on Rails `shopify_app` gem:

We actually found an issue there - which might help others, to.

In:
`ShopifyApp::RequireKnownShop#check_shop_known`

`.../gems/shopify_app-18.0.2/app/controllers/concerns/shopify_app/require_known_shop.rb:24`

[image: code screenshot]

We found an issue that basically the gem was just checking if the shop in DB is found by the domain name, and if it was, then it assumed that all is ok.
But the app didn't get installed.
So we needed to check that it can actually connect to Shopify API with the existing token - and if we cannot, then need to redirect to `/login?shop=...` so that it gets properly installed.
Probably `shopify_app` gem shouldn't check that the token is valid/needs to be re-generated - but it would be nice if it did check that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Paul Odeon said after the user uninstalled the app, you need to delete your old shop information from your database.

I just want to mention how to do that with Laravel.

[doc](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/webhook#top)

on this page, you can find `app/uninstalled` webhook.

when the user installed the app, on the first page you should create the webhook.

in `Laravel` it's like this:

```
    $shop = Auth::user();

    $p = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/2021-07/webhooks.json', []);
    $webhooks = $p['body']['container']['webhooks'];

    if(count($webhooks) === 0){
        $p = $shop->api()->rest('POST', '/admin/api/2021-07/webhooks.json', [
            "webhook" => [
                "topic" => "app/uninstalled",
                "address" => env('APP_URL') . "/api/uninstalled/" . $shop->id,
                "format" => "json"
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

api.php:

```
Route::post('/uninstalled/{user_id}', 'WebhookController@uninstallAppWebhook');
```

controller:

```
public function uninstallAppWebhook($userId){
        \DB::table('users')->delete($userId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

But what if the scenario is this, you cannot create a webhook before installing app
Check this one:
https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/issues/1071

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ruby shopify gem and you are finding this message only on the reinstalling app cases, you need to set nil on the **shop.shopify_token** and the **shop.shopify_domain** fields after you receive the uninstall webhook.

On my case, I'm using the now deprecated field "shop.myshopify_domain" to save the domain when the user uninstall the app.

If the user reinstalls (even many months after), find the old SQL row and switch the rows. That way the user will find his previous data.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with our sales channel too and the reason was that shopify's **"APP_UNINSTALLED"** webhook does not get called properly or some delay happens so the session_token does not get cleared (which you might be doing in that webhook handler). And because of using an expired token, you end up on that page.

How we fixed it was we retrieve the saved session from session storage and use it to hit any shopify admin api and if that fails with a 401 or 403 error then we assume that it is an expired token and clear it.

Something like this:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  if (typeof req.query.shop !== "string") {
    res.status(500);
    return res.send("No shop provided");
  }

  const shop = Shopify.Utils.sanitizeShop(req.query.shop) || "";
  const sessions = await Shopify.Context.SESSION_STORAGE.findSessionsByShop(shop);

  const { AccessScope } = await import(
  `@shopify/shopify-api/dist/rest-resources/${Shopify.Context.API_VERSION}/index.js`
  );

  const scope = await AccessScope.all({
    session: sessions[0],
  }).catch(async (err) => {
    // We check for the error status code and clear our storage
    if (err.response?.code === 401 || err.response?.code === 403) {
      sessions.forEach((session) => redisClient.del(session.id));
      await AppInstallations.delete(shop);
    }
  });
  const appInstalled = await AppInstallations.includes(shop);

  if (!appInstalled) {
    return redirectToAuth(req, res, app);
  }

  if (Shopify.Context.IS_EMBEDDED_APP && req.query.embedded !== "1") {
    const embeddedUrl = Shopify.Utils.getEmbeddedAppUrl(req);

    return res.redirect(embeddedUrl + req.path);
  }

  return handle(req, res);
)};

const AppInstallations = {
  includes: async function (shopDomain: string) {
    if (Shopify.Context.SESSION_STORAGE.findSessionsByShop) {
      const shopSessions =
        await Shopify.Context.SESSION_STORAGE.findSessionsByShop(shopDomain);
      if (shopSessions.length > 0) {
        for (const session of shopSessions) {
          if (session.accessToken) return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  },

  delete: async function (shopDomain: string) {
    if (Shopify.Context.SESSION_STORAGE.findSessionsByShop) {
      const shopSessions =
        await Shopify.Context.SESSION_STORAGE.findSessionsByShop(shopDomain);
      if (shopSessions.length > 0) {
        if (Shopify.Context.SESSION_STORAGE.deleteSessions) {
          await Shopify.Context.SESSION_STORAGE.deleteSessions(
            shopSessions.map((session) => session.id)
          );
        }
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Where do you import AppInstallations?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro AppInstallations is a function I have exported that has two methods **includes** and **delete** . I have added that function in the code block above. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was getting that error because the name of the app was the same as the name of an app that i had installed previously.

I solved this by simply changing the name of the app from. `micro-app` to `micro-app2`.

once `micro-app2` was installed, then I tried to install `micro-app` again, and it work fine

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for us. We resolved this another way.

We found that the `/web/public` directory in the boilerplate (after running `npm run build`) contained BOTH an `index.html` and an `index.php`.

Nginx prioritizes incorrectly prioritizes the `index.html` - deleting this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, When we install any app from the shopify app store, It'll create a new store in our user table. If you are using an `Osiset/Laravel` or `ohmybrew/laravel-Shopify`  package then you have to **delete** your store first from your database or create a new webhook to enable `uninstall` functionality using this below code.

Add this code to your `.env` file

```
SHOPIFY_UNINSTALLED=APP_UNINSTALLED
SHOPIFY_UNINSTALLED_ADDRESS=yourdomain.com/webhook/app-uninstalled
```

This webhooks is used to uninstall your app from store and delete your store's entry from database.